# How to save state of spinner using Java Android

Tags: android, eclipse, spinner, state

I am trying to save the state of a spinner select. So if I select a choice in the spinner and move into a different activity, then coming back to the activity with the spinner that choice should still be selected.  I found some tutorials but the ones of I have tried are deprecated.

Here's my spinner:

```
   //language selection list    
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.language_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

           // storing string resources into Array
            lang_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language_list);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected : " + lang_list[index], 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           choice =  spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


            final ImageView country_flag = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.country);
            String s=((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();
            if(s.equals("English"))
                country_flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.eng_spinner));
            if(s.equals("German"))
                country_flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.german_spinner));
            if(s.equals("French"))
                country_flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.french_spinner));
            if(s.equals("Spanish"))
                country_flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spanish_spinner));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the current spinner's state on `onSaveInstanceState()` by putting the date, time, etc. into the bundle with a key by getting the index of the spinner's current selected position. Afterwards, on your `onCreate()`, check if `bundle == null`, and if it is not `null` (which it shouldn't be if your activity was recreated due to resume), you retrieve the values you stored in it with the keys. Finally, manually set the values to your spinner using `Spinner.setPosition()` inside the `onCreate()`.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

This should be a good read.